# Black spots in normal map

Tags: texture-baking

i'm trying to make a normal map out of a high poly tyre. But i always get black spots in the normal map (see red circles). Left is the originial, right the low poly with the normal map.
[image]

Here is the blender file
[tyre.blend](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/29417)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Subsurf modifier is set to the "Simple" algorithm, which in this case adds a lot of extra geometry without giving you any actual geometric smoothing (The normals are sampled more densely though which makes some difference in appearance). In any case you still have those strong edges in your geometry, that, combined with problably some form of floating point precision irregularities during raytracing give you these 'artifacts'. If you switch the SubSurf algorithm to "Catmull-Clark", remodel your tire pattern to make use of close proximity edge loops and the likes to retain the original shapes while gaining actual geometric smoothing via the SubSurf modifier, and then reattempt baking the normals, I would very much believe that your artifacts will be gone.

If anything (or all) of this sounds like gibberish, please let me know and i'll try to clarify further. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I spent the whole day till i finally got it right looking. Here is the result with the 2048px normal map: http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=71813.

Comment: But could u explain further how i could retain the original form while using catmull? Cause as my picture shows my result is much smoother now.

Comment: [This](http://cgcookie.com/blender/2013/06/21/tips-creating-sharp-edges-modeling/) explains three techniques for creating sharp(er) edges in a subsurf-smoothed model, which is exactly what you will need to do! You will pick up a better feeling for how these subdivision algorithms behave as you go along, just keep experimenting and don't get discouraged, it's really not all that magical as you will discover soon. ;) More insights on this for instance also [here](http://cgcookie.com/blender/2012/10/29/blender-conference-2012-complex-topology/)